# Insert and update multi item into database in the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have an empty data base.
I want to add multi records into data base.
while inserting record to data base i want to check if my product inserted in same date donot add it again(i want to change some it's filed and update it's content).
i used this code but it just add some data into data base (it can't check for existing product.)

```
var AllData = ClsDataBase.Database.InsertProductTbls;

 foreach(item in AllData)
        {
          //Update  
          if (Exist(datefa))
            {
            var query = ClsDataBase.Database.CustomerProductTbls.SingleOrDefault
                    (data => data.CustomerId == AllData .CustomerId );

                    int? LastProductTotal = query.CustomerProducTtotal;
                    query.CustomerProducTtotal = LastProductTotal + ClsInsertProduct._InsertProductNumber;

                }
                //Insert 
                else
                {
                    _CustomerProductTbl = new CustomerProductTbl();
                    _CustomerProductTbl.CustomerId = AllData ._CustomerId;
                    _CustomerProductTbl.CustomerProductDateFa = AllData.datefa
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    ClsDataBase.Database.AddToCustomerProductTbls(_CustomerProductTbl);
                }
            }
        }
        ClsDataBase.Database.SaveChanges();
```

if i use `ClsDataBase.Database.SaveChanges();` for both update and insert part i will return this error:

```
An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.
```

please help.

Comment: The text you posted just says there's an inner exception. Please post it also.

Comment: Exactly i want to add multi filed into db and while adding check for  filed existing by date if exist donot add it.any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by opening database conection for each repeat loop:

```
foreach(item in AllData)
        {
           using (StorageEntities context = new StorageEntities())
           {
         //Update  
          if (Exist(datefa))
            {
            var query = ClsDataBase.Database.CustomerProductTbls.SingleOrDefault
                    (data => data.CustomerId == AllData .CustomerId );

                    int? LastProductTotal = query.CustomerProducTtotal;
                    query.CustomerProducTtotal = LastProductTotal + ClsInsertProduct._InsertProductNumber;

                }
                //Insert 
                else
                {
                    _CustomerProductTbl = new CustomerProductTbl();
                    _CustomerProductTbl.CustomerId = AllData ._CustomerId;
                    _CustomerProductTbl.CustomerProductDateFa = AllData.datefa;
                    ClsDataBase.Database.AddToCustomerProductTbls(_CustomerProductTbl);
                }
                ClsDataBase.Database.SaveChanges();
            }
         }
```